# Add Telegram bot to group

Tags: c#, bots, telegram-bot

I'm in a one-to-one communication with my bot now he should post a button which prompts the user to select a chat. This works with:

```
InlineKeyboardButton selectGroup = new InlineKeyboardButton("Add to Group");
selectGroup.SwitchInlineQuery = "test";
selectGroup.CallbackData = null;
selectGroup.Url = null;

var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
{
    new[] // first row
    {
        selectGroup
    },
});
```

Now the bot should be added to the selected chat. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Use an `url` button with https://telegram.me/botuser?startgroup=

Comment: jab this works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [deep-linking](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) feature:

Send an url button with a link to `https://telegram.me/botuser?startgroup=foo`